# Navigation Bar Button Hide When animation set as YES

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am setting Back and next Button as Navigation Bar item left button and right button.which have code below as

```
 //  Back Button

UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

   [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigatehome)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = aBarButtonItem;

//Next Button
 aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigatenext)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:aBarButtonItem]
```

And Problem when `animated:YES` in statement

```
  CSA_info *h1=[[CSA_info alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:h1 animated:YES];
```

It shows as below image

[image: image when button not shown]

If uses `animated:No` then showed as below

[image]

I am adding a image in as subview in navigation Bar so it hides the buttons.

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"title bar.png"];
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 
 imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-5, 0, 330, 44); 
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:2];
```

I required to add that image in navigation.

Why it so, Any Help ?

Comment: remove the images and set the background color of the button then please let me know if you are still facing the same problen.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more that where are you setting the right & left button of UINavigationBar . Is it in the CSA_info class ?

Comment: you must impliment this code in to viewViewAppear

Comment: @Nitin I tried it to , i am implementing it in viewWillAppeare.

Comment: @Divz I did it too and still facing problem.

Comment: your attach code is working for me may i am creating demo of it please put full code of setting navigationbar image.

Comment: @nitin I edited the code please find it.

Comment: @ArpitKumar check my new Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put title bar image in secondViewcontroller like bellow in ViewDidLoad

```
UIImage* imageback = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back_Button.png"];
                CGRect frameimgback = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
                backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimgback];
                [backButton setBackgroundImage:imageback forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Back)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"titileBar.png"];
                [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

                UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you problem properly then following solution should work,

You need to add the code in viewDidLoad method of the view controller. Please refer the below code

```
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:kButtonFrame];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kBackButtonImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigatehome)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = aBarButtonItem;

UIButton *nextButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:kButtonFrame];
[nextButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kNextButtonImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigatenext)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItemRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:nextButton];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:aBarButtonItemRight];
```

This should work fine even you animated while pushing the view controller.

Comment: Do you want same buttons to be present in both the views ?

Comment: Then you have to use same code in your CSA_info class also. Inside viewDidLoad method.